# How do I access to a locally installed Openbravo

Tags: openbravo

I succesfully built Openbravo on a Debian 10 machine following this guide: http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/Installation/Custom/Openbravo_Setup

However, when I navigate to `http://localhost/openbravo` I get a "service unavailable" page.

Everything went fine at building time and all services are up. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Because it will run on tomcat try http://localhost:8080/openbravo

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify port 8080 (as in http://localhost:8080/openbravo)